# Confusion about ROOT Certificate and Client certificates

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate2

I am struggling to understand how certificates work.

We have a website, with a ssl certificate signed by our CA.

We would like to use Azure Point-To-Site VPN, which also needs a root certificate.
From this root certificate, we can create multiple client certificates to authenticate against the point to site VPN.
Microsoft has described that here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-certificates-point-to-site

I got this working by generating a self signed root certificate, generating client certificates for this root certificate and passing the CER to the point to site configuration in Azure.

Would it be possible to use my SSL certificate to sign the point-to-site root certificate? So I mean using my SSL certificate as CA for my point-to-site root certificate so clients installing the p2s client certificates, can see it is trusted via our website?

Comment: `use my SSL certificate to sign the point-to-site root certificate?` -- no, you can't. But you mentioned, you have your own CA. Why not to use it to issue all required certificates?

Comment: Is it possible to let my own self signed root certificate (used for point to site vpn) be signed by my known CA? This way, client installing the client certificates, should be able to see that it is a trusted certificate?

Comment: You don't need to have another root certificate or whatever else. Use your existing CA to issue certificates to VPN endpoints. VPN client and server should trust your CA.

Comment: For now I do have only one self signed root certificate. But wouldn't it work if I did not self sign my CA, but let it sign by a known CA (DigiCert for example), so users installing my root certificate, can immediately see it is trusted? Or is this complete nonsense?

Comment: Commercial CA won't give you CA certificate that easy (it is doable, but you are unlikely applicable to this option). You said that you already have CA. Install it (if not yet installed) on your client devices and servers. Use this CA to issue certificates to VPN endpoints.